# Trying to use mobx in react native but heremes

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx-react

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchLoginResponse' of undefined, js engine: hermes

```
class LoginStore {
    count=0;
    constructor(){
        makeObservable(this,{
                fetchLoginResponse: action,
                count: observable,
        });

    }
    fetchLoginResponse() {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
    }
 
}

export default loginstore = new LoginStore();
```

const handleLoginPress = () => {

```
     loginstore.fetchLoginResponse();
```

};

Comment: The `loginstore` is undefined, which means it's not available in the namespace in which it's being called. There's no way to say why this is happening as you've not included how you are importing `loginstore`.

Comment: import {loginstore} from '../../mobx/LoginStore'

Comment: how to import then this can you give me sample solution

Comment: `loginstore` is a default export but you're importing it as a named import. You should use `import loginstore from '../../mobx/LoginStore'` (remove the `{` and `}`)